# How to retrieve information from hashtables in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hashtable, clisp

I want to ask the user for input in LISP. I then want to see if this input is the key for a hashtable value and then retrieve the value corresponding to this key in the hashtable. I don't know how to do this and when I run the code that I am posting, it terminates before taking input from the user. Please help and thank you very much!!

```
(defparameter *KB* (make-hash-table))

(setf (gethash '(Robot Robbie) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Likes Robbie Samantha) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Dog Rover) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Bark Rover) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Likes Robbie Chocolate) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Lives Robbie California) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Likes Robbie ice-cream) *KB*) T)
(setf (gethash '(Eats Robbie petrol) *KB*) T)

(format t "Please enter a well formed function")
(terpri)
(defvar *apple* (read-line))
(terpri)
 (format t "~a ~%"*apple*)
(terpri)
```

Comment: I think you have two issues here: 1. Using user input and 2. using lists as hash keys. You will find several examples in others question for prompting for and validating user input, i guess.

If you want to use lists as keys of your `hash-table` you should make sure that you are using an appropriate test-function, i.e. `equalp`.

Furthermore, you do not need to use `terpri` after `format`. Check the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) for further details.

Comment: First of all, try to get the answer by reading documentation. The [Common Lisp Cookbook chapter](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/hashes.html) is certainly useful. The definite reference documentation is the [CLHS chapter](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm).

Comment: @BrunoHaible I suggest you to link to the newer Cookbook! https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#hash-table

Comment: Thanks guys! The cookbook was really helpful!